# Typescript: defining an object for a json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object, definition

I need to put this json

```
"id": "x1",
"severity": 100,
"timestamp": 1599230966,
"attr1": "...",
"attr2": "...",
"origin": [{
    "id": "x3",
    "severity": 75,
    "timestamp": 1599230366,
    "attr1": "...",
    "origin": [{
            "id": "x2",
            "severity": 50,
            "timestamp": 1599229766,
            "attr1": "...",
            "attr2": 555,
            "attr3": "...",
            "origin": []
        },
        {
            "id": "x1",
            "severity": 25,
            "timestamp": 1599229166,
            "attr1": "...",
            "origin": []
        }
    ]
}]
```

into an object, and I just don't know how to define the object that is suitable for this json. I've struggled a lot,so please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: what does mean by put this JSON into an object? You can assign JSON response to an object by simply `const obj = response`? can you please be more specific or post your effort what you had tried?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I need to create an object that will hold data from this json and I also need to refer to its attributes, like id and other. I've tried to declare an object that has all the attributes from the json, but didn't work. I think it's because the json comes every time with different count of attributes and I can't just hardcode it only for this sample

Comment: Where that JSON is coming from? as I said all you need to assign this JSON to an variable and then you can access it. better to create stackblitz

Comment: So if I do just const obj = response I can display it in html for example like {{obj.id}}? I'll try to make stack blitz, but i have to figure out how to express my problem first :D cos I really cannot

Comment: Yes correct but for that `obj` shouldn't be `const obj` but a class variable `obj`

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort put in helping me. My problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an interface and assign it to the result.

```
export interface Origin{
  id?: string;
  severity?: number;
  timestamp?: number;
  attr1?: string;
  attr2?: string;
  orginArray: Origin[];
}
```

in you controller

```
private origin: Origin;
```

and in function of return the result

```
this.origin = result;
```

// Second option

//main.ts

```
export interface IOrigin {
      id?: string;
      severity?: number;
      timestamp?: number;
      attr1?: string;
      attr2?: string;
      origin: IOrigin[];
    }

class Origin implements IOrigin {
      id?: string;
      severity?: number;
      timestamp?: number;
      attr1?: string;
      attr2?: string;
      origin: Origin[];
  constructor(values: IOrigin) {
      this.id = values.id;
      // assign all your attributes
      this.origin = values.origin !== undefined ? toOriginList(values.origin) : undefined;
  }
}


function toOriginList(values: IOrigin[]): Origin[] {
    return values.map(tree => new Origin(tree));
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: Ok, just one more question, How can I acces the Origin array within the origin variable?

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't fill up the array for some reason

Comment: and the origin[] remains undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'd add to @A.khalifa response that, you can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn this JSON into an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something

assume that response is any API response

```
obj: any; // you can create interface and add type

response = {
  "id": "x1",
  "severity": 100,
  "timestamp": 1599230966,
  "attr1": "...",
  "attr2": "...",
  "origin": [{
     "id": "x3",
     "severity": 75,
     "timestamp": 1599230366,
     "attr1": "...",
     "origin": [{
        "id": "x2",
        "severity": 50,
        "timestamp": 1599229766,
        "attr1": "...",
        "attr2": 555,
        "attr3": "...",
        "origin": []
    },
    {
        "id": "x1",
        "severity": 25,
        "timestamp": 1599229166,
        "attr1": "...",
        "origin": []
    }
  ]
}]
```

assign response to your class variable so that you can access it from template

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.obj = response
}
```

or in any method where you are getting response

```
fetch() {
 // some logic to get api response

 // assign response to obj
 this.obj = response
 }
```

In template you can access complete boject

```
<div> {{ obj.id }} </div>
```

Iterate over array of object

```
<div *ngFor="let origin of obj.origin"> 
  {{ origin.id }}
  {{ origin.severity }}
  {{ origin.timestamp }}
  ....
</div>
```